# locale.CHINA is not working

Tags: java

No matter what i do, i'll keep getting "China: ?100.00". What's wrong with my code?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    /* Read input */
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
    scanner.close();

    /* Create NumberFormats using Locales */
    NumberFormat china  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA);

    /* Print output */        
    System.out.println("China: "  + china.format(payment));
}
```

Comment: The console where you are printing the output of your program most likely uses a font that does not contain the Chinese currency code character, so you get a '?' instead of the actual character.

Comment: Which version of OS are you using? Specifically in case of Windows, you need to install a Language pack separately.

Comment: @Jesper, I actually do some exercise in Hackerrank website. When I post my code in the website, I still didn't get the correct currency character, instead a weird character appeared..

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan, I'm using windows 7..

Comment: What is the 'weird' character? And are you sure that it is incorrect? Maybe the weird character is actually the appropriate currency symbol.

Comment: It does work on my system, its shows China: ￥100.00, Like I said before, you need to install Language pack on all systems using this program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
china=DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA).format(100.10);
```